# import a symbol from another package just to add it to an api

Tags: python, python-import, policy

Say, I want to add a symbol `some_function` from package `a` to the API of package `b`, because that symbol does exactly what it should, but to packages using `b`, the fact that `some_function` is really implemented in package `a` is an implementation detail of `b`.

Now, I know that just putting `from a import some_function` into `b` will do the trick, but first, my IDE will complain that `some_function` is never used, and secondly, anyone looking at that file will think that's just a redundant import, probably left-over from an earlier version of that code.

How do I add `some_function` to `b` in a way that makes it clear to the IDE and to readers of the code of `b` that `some_function` is imported there on purpose and meant as part of `b`'s API?

(one way to do this is to have something like `def another_function(): some_function()`, but that seems like a large footprint for so simple a task)

Answer (score 4):

To add `some_function` from package `a` to the API of package `b` in a way that clearly indicates its intentional inclusion and (potentially) avoids IDE warnings, you can use the `__all__` attribute in `b`'s `__init__.py` file.

Here's what you can do:

1. Open the `__init__.py` file of package `b` (if it doesn't exist, create it).
2. Import `some_function` from package `a` using `from a import some_function`.
3. Add `some_function` to the `__all__` list in `__init__.py`.

The modified `__init__.py` file would look like this:

```py
from a import some_function

__all__ = ['some_function']
```

By adding `some_function` to `__all__`, you explicitly specify the symbols that are part of `b`'s API. This approach helps both IDEs and readers of the code understand that `some_function` is intentionally included as part of `b`'s API and not a redundant import.

Comment: Nice. I don't suppose `__all__ = [some_function]` will work, will it?  That would make it a bit more robust for tool-based refactorings.

Comment: No, unfortunately using `__all__ = [some_function]` will not work. The `__all__` attribute is expected to be a list of strings that represent the names of the symbols to be exported. https://rules.sonarsource.com/python/RSPEC-2823

Answer (score 2):

The pythonic way is to use the `__all__` variable in your module's namespace, as referenced in the [Python 3 Documentation Modules Importing * From a Package](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#importing-from-a-package)

You would (at a minimum) have:

```
__all__ = [ "some_function", ]
```

You will now need to add **all** of the symbols you want to export "officially" from the package to this list.

This does not change any behavior, except for `from b import *` but provides the indicator that the import was not an oversight.